# Java Calculate all possible combinations of given int array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to construct a program that would take an array of int({1,2,3} and a length value and calculate all possible combinations of this array.

For example:

```
int[] arr= new char[] {0,1};
int[] tes  = new int[3];
possiblecomb(2, arr,tes,0);
```

This will output:

```
 00
 10
 01
 11
```

But i keep getting a Stack overflow error when i try to call the possiblecomb in the for loop

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

 public class Program {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create an arr to work with
    int[] test = new int[] {0,1};
     int[] tes  = new int[3];
    // Find all possible combinations of this arr in the string size of 3
    possiblecomb(3, test,tes,0);
}

public static void possiblecomb(int maxLength, int[] nums, int[] curr,int end) {

    // If the current array has reached it's maximum length
    if(end == maxLength) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(curr));

    // Else add each number from the numbs to new array and process these new arrays again
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int[] oldCurr = curr.clone();
            curr[end]= nums[i];
            possiblecomb(maxLength,nums,curr,end++);
            curr = oldCurr.clone();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Try moving your recursive call outside of the for.

You are using the for in order to copy contents.

Your end variable will eventually increment above max lenght, and your (==) comparison won't be a stopper.

Take the example where num.Length = 2 and end is 2 :

You will call your function once with end = 3 which will stop and print inside the recursive call, and next, when i == 1 your end will be 4 and the recursive call won't break.

If you want to avoid the infinite recurssion with your current code in order to better debug with output, put the break condition

```
if (end>=maxLength)
```

Answer (score 3):

As @MichaelCMS said you never stop the recursion, hence a stack overflow.

If you don't mind using `Lists` instead of `arrays` this is a solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program {
  private static List<List<Integer>> combinations(List<Integer> list, int maxLength) {
    return combinations(list, maxLength, new ArrayList(), new ArrayList());
  }

  private static List<List<Integer>> combinations(List<Integer> list, int length, List<Integer> current, List<List<Integer>> result) {
    if (length == 0) {
      List<List<Integer>> newResult =  new ArrayList<>(result);
      newResult.add(current);
      return newResult;
    }

    List<List<List<Integer>>> res3 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer i : list) {
      List<Integer> newCurrent = new ArrayList<>(current);
      newCurrent.add(i);
      res3.add(combinations(list, length - 1, newCurrent, result));
    }

    List<List<Integer>> res2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<List<Integer>> lst : res3) {
      res2.addAll(lst);
    }
    return res2;
  }

  public static void printCombinations(List<Integer> list, int maxLength) {
    List<List<Integer>> combs = combinations(list, maxLength);
    for (List<Integer> lst : combs) {
      String line = "";
      for (Integer i : lst) {
        line += i;
      }
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(0, 1);
    printCombinations(l, 2);
  }
}
```

That gives you:

```
00
01
10
11
```